# Stop Azure Kubernetes Pod and the restart again after sometime

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I want to stop my running AKS pod. Can someone please guide me? how i can stop my aks running pod and the restart again?Thank you

Comment: You mean other than with `kubectl`?

Comment: you can scale down the deployment then scale back up when needed again

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg yes

Comment: @Thomas the deployment is through helm

Comment: @EhsanEllahi The deployment method is independent from the means of scaling. Scaling a workload can ALWAYS be done via `kubectl`.

Comment: If there's a deployment, all you need to do is delete the pod via `kubectl delete pod`. The deployment will then start a new pod.